# Newbie: OOP working with different class-datatypes and loop through them

Tags: vb.net, oop

I'm relatively new to OOP. Lets say I have three different objects/classes defined, like

```
Public Class Part
    Private m_Name As String = ""
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return m_Name
        End Get
    End Property

    something...
End Class

Public Class Assembly 
    Private m_Name As String = ""
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return m_Name
        End Get
    End Property

    something...
End Class

Public Class Drawing
    Private m_Name As String = ""
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return m_Name
        End Get
    End Property

    something...
End Class
```

Now I have a list of all instances of those objects in another class, like:

```
Public Class Main
    Private m_ListOfObjects As List(Of Objects)
    Private Sub run()
       something...
    End Sub
End Class
```

Imagine a code which adds each instance of those three classes (Part, Assembly and Drawing) to this `m_ListOfObjects`. Now I have a loop which loops trough the whole list, like

```
Dim Obj As Object
For Each Obj In m_ListObObjects
   Debug.Print(Obj.Name)
End For
```

My Questions is now: IntelliSense is not able to show me if the property `Name` exists for the Object `Obj`. Well thats clear, because Visual Studio does not know that I will use the classes `Part`, `Assembly` and `Drawing`. How can I solve that issue?

It feels like a hacky way when I use something like this:

```
CType(Obj, Part).Name
```

Then Visual Studio knows that I refer to the `Part` Class. But What can I do if I loop through different objects in a liste and refer to a property each class will have? Or maybe my approach is completely off the track of OOP? Do I miss the opportunity to implement an interface?

Comment: Well, you're not entirely wrong.  But would suggest there are better ways to model this, and your question is probably more suited to the [software engineering stack](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).  That said, if it was me, I would have a base class with common properties members, then part, assembly, drawing inherit.  That way your list is now more narrowly typed.  Still have to Ctype when working with class specific members.

Comment: I would be also avoid loading multiple types for different uses into the same collection of objects unless required.  If they are different enough to be different, generally keep them different.  As a general rule, I avoid declaring objects as Object, kind of defeats the purpose of having a strongly typed language, can't remember doing it in the last 15yrs at least.

Comment: I can't keep them strictly separate. The code is used in an AddIn for a CAD-Programm. Naturally an assembly can consists of multiple sub assemblies and parts mixed together. With my example, I don't see a possibility to declare `Obj` with a different datatype then Object?

Comment: That's what I'm getting at though. Declare a class with the common properties, call it MyBaseClass (like Name etc).  Then part, assembly, drawing inherit MyBaseClass.  Then you would be doing things like List(of MyBaseClass).  Yes, if needing properties specific to one of the 3 inherited classes, still need to cast it to the correct type but overall makes you code much more maintainable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For maximum flexibility what you want is a combination of base classes and interfaces. I'll model vehicles as a way to illustrate how. Lets say we have this:-

```
Public Class Car
    Public Property SteeringWheelSize As Integer
    Public Property WheelCount As Integer
    Public Property GasTankSize As Integer
    Public Property TypeOfFuel As String

End Class

Public Class Truck
    Public Property SteeringWheelSize As Integer
    Public Property WheelCount As Integer
    Public Property CargoSpace As Integer
    Public Property GasTankSize As Integer
    Public Property TypeOfFuel As String

End Class

Public Class Steamroller
    Public Property SteeringWheelSize As Integer
    Public Property GasTankSize As Integer
    Public Property TypeOfFuel As String
End Class
Public Class Boat
    Public Property CargoSpace As Integer
    Public Property GasTankSize As Integer
    Public Property TypeOfFuel As String

End Class
Public Class Plane
    Public Property WheelCount As Integer
    Public Property CargoSpace As Integer
    Public Property GasTankSize As Integer
    Public Property TypeOfFuel As String

End Class

Public Class MotorCycle
    Public Property WheelCount As Integer
    Public Property GasTankSize As Integer
    Public Property TypeOfFuel As String
End Class
```

These all represent different types of vehicles. All of them have a number of things in common but there are also a number of things they don't. If you tried putting all of them together in a list as is, it would be tedious trying to filter out who has what. This is where interfaces and inheritance can help.

Lets start with what all of them have in common. They all use fuel or some kind that is held in a tank. This is how what we use for our base class:-

```
Public Class CombustionVehicle
    Public Property GasTankSize As Integer
    Public Property TypeOfFuel As String
End Class
```

This will be the base class for all types of vehicles. Now there are things that certain vehicles have in common that the others don't. For example, some have wheels, some have steering wheels. We put these things onto interfaces:-

```
Public Interface ISteeringWheel
    Property SteeringWheelSize As Integer
End Interface

Public Interface ICargoVehicle
    Property CargoSpace As Integer
End Interface

Public Interface IWheeledVehicle
    Property WheelCount As Integer
End Interface
```

Now we are ready to model our vehicles properly. We inherit from the base class and then we implement the interfaces based on what kind of vehicle we want to represent. Here is it in full:-

```
Public Class Car
    Inherits CombustionVehicle

    Implements ISteeringWheel, IWheeledVehicle

    Public Property SteeringWheelSize As Integer Implements ISteeringWheel.SteeringWheelSize
    Public Property WheelCount As Integer Implements IWheeledVehicle.WheelCount
End Class

Public Class Truck
    Inherits CombustionVehicle

    Implements ISteeringWheel, IWheeledVehicle, ICargoVehicle

    Public Property SteeringWheelSize As Integer Implements ISteeringWheel.SteeringWheelSize
    Public Property WheelCount As Integer Implements IWheeledVehicle.WheelCount
    Public Property CargoSpace As Integer Implements ICargoVehicle.CargoSpace
End Class

Public Class Steamroller
    Inherits CombustionVehicle

    Implements ISteeringWheel

    Public Property SteeringWheelSize As Integer Implements ISteeringWheel.SteeringWheelSize

End Class

Public Class Boat
    Inherits CombustionVehicle

    Implements ICargoVehicle

    Public Property CargoSpace As Integer Implements ICargoVehicle.CargoSpace
End Class

Public Class Plane
    Inherits CombustionVehicle

    Implements IWheeledVehicle, ICargoVehicle

    Public Property WheelCount As Integer Implements IWheeledVehicle.WheelCount
    Public Property CargoSpace As Integer Implements ICargoVehicle.CargoSpace
End Class

Public Class MotorCycle
    Inherits CombustionVehicle

    Implements IWheeledVehicle

    Public Property WheelCount As Integer Implements IWheeledVehicle.WheelCount
End Class
```

Now you could store the all in a single array or list:-

```
Dim allVehicles As CombustionVehicle()
```

Let's say you wanted print the steering wheel size of all vehicles with steering wheels, you could do this:-

```
        For Each v As ISteeringWheel In allVehicles.OfType(Of ISteeringWheel)
            Debug.WriteLine(v.SteeringWheelSize)
        Next
```

That loop filters out all elements that implement ISteeringWheel. You also get the benefit of the intellisense when typing out the code. Here are some other filters:-

```
        'Print the gas tank size of all vehicles
        For Each v As CombustionVehicle In allVehicles
            Debug.WriteLine(v.GasTankSize)
        Next

        'Use LINQ to sum the cargo space of all vehicles in the array
        'with cargo space
        Debug.WriteLine(allVehicles.
                        OfType(Of ICargoVehicle).
                        Sum(Function(v) v.CargoSpace))

        'Use LINQ to print out the least number of wheels found
        'on any vehicle that has wheels
        Debug.WriteLine(allVehicles.
                        OfType(Of IWheeledVehicle).
                        Min(Function(v) v.WheelCount))
```

Note that with all of these we get intellisense support and protection from mistakes by strong typing. The compiler won't allow us to compile code that tries to get the properties of vehicles that aren't there.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Where do I put all those interface declarations - into the base class? Or new file?

Comment: You could put the base class, the interfaces and the derived class into a single file or you could separate them according to your own tastes. It's really up to you how you want to organize them.